# How to stream data from Snowflake SQL output to S3 on AWS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL to run on three Snowflake tables hosted on AWS account. I would like to stream any new records based on the output of my SQL to an S3 bucket using possibly Kafka or any other streaming service. What are my options to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can unload data directly into an S3 bucket :

1. Create storage integration.
2. Create stage or specify bucket url directly in the query.

copy into s3://mybucket/unload/ from mytable storage_integration = s3_int;

Ref : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html

Comment: Thank you. How do I make my Snowflake SQL to stream to the s3 bucket like we can do the other way around Kafka?